# Borrow money from a friend in US

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, money-transfer

I want to borrow some money from my friend in US. It's about 500,000 Rupees. Approx 7500 USD. I will return it in a week or so.

Will both these transactions be taxed ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give your country as well as your friend's country.  I'm guessing that rupees means India, but it would be better if you stated that explicitly.  Also, how are you transferring the money from and to your friend?

Comment: It would also be courteous to mention approximately how much that sum is in USD, and write it as 500,000 rupees (the word "lakh" is practically never used outside India.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are Indian Citizen / Resident for Tax purposes. Your friend in US Citizen / Resident for tax purposes.

As you are borrowing these funds and returning, this would NOT be treated as Gift but as Loan. Ensure that you have the right documentation in place.

There is no tax when you receive the funds/loan or rebate when you pay back the loan.

From India [FEMA (Foreign Exchange Management Act)](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FAQView.aspx?Id=52#f3) point of view, if you take loan from friends, you cannot by default repatriate funds. You have to take special permission to repatriate the funds out of India.